# Fibers of a scheme over $\text{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to construct connected scheme $X$ over $\text{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$ such that for $p\neq0$ the fiber $X_p=X\times_{\text{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}}k(p)$ over the prime ideal $(p)$ contains precisely $p$ points over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

The same question for $p+1$ and $p-1$.

Comment: What examples of schemes do you know?

Answer (score 6):

Take the canonical morphism $X=\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}=\operatorname {Spec} (\mathbb Z[T])\to \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb Z$, which has  fiber $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb F_p}=\operatorname {Spec} (\mathbb F_p[T])$ over $(p)\in \mathbb Z$.
This fiber has exactly $p$ points rational over $\mathbb F_p$ .

**Edit**
The canonical morphism  $Y=\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z}=\operatorname {Proj} \mathbb Z[T,U]\to \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb Z$ has as fiber over $(p)\in \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb Z$ the projective line $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}=\operatorname {Proj} \mathbb F_p[T,U]$, and that fiber has exactly $p+1$ points rational over $\mathbb F_p$-points.
This answers miguels's supplementary question in his comment.

Comment: Thanks. What about $p+1$ points?

Comment: Dear miguels, I have answered this supplementary question in an Edit.

Comment: thank you for your answers. Can you give an example with $p-1$ points in fiber?

Comment: @miguels The affine line and the projective line over $\mathbb Z$ answered your first two questions. To construct schemes with less points just remove points from these schemes. For instance, you can remove the zero section of $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$ to get a scheme with $p-1$ rational points in its fiber over $(p)$.